# How to read and publish to two different topics at the same time in mqtt

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

I have created a class Mqtt that contains the definitions of the functions of all the necessary callbacks, and I want to subscribe to two occupancy sensor (actually I have even more) using a single object of the class Mqtt, then based on the sensor that publishes "1", I need to send a PUBLISH message to turn the lights on. However, once I send "1" to `testtopic/4` and then to `testtopic/5`, messages are sent at first t bedroom but then to the kitchen and no more to bedrooms. Here is the main code:

```
from class_mqtt import Mqtt
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys
import threading
import time
from MongoDB import is_circadian_Light


Broker            = "broker.mqttdashboard.com"
username          = "growthtechnology"
password          = "growthtechnology"
PortaBroker       = 1883
KeepAliveBroker   = 60
client_name       = "Local"

light = Mqtt(topic_sub)
# I have two sensors
occupancy_sensor = Mqtt([("testtopic/4", 0), ("testtopic/5", 0)])
tunable_light = Light("deviceID")
# I used test as lights to subscribe and be sure to receive messages
test = Mqtt("testtopic/Kitchen")

try:

    print("[STATUS] Initialising MQTT...")
    #Initialising mqtt
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.connect(Broker, PortaBroker, KeepAliveBroker)
    # test
    client.on_connect     = test.connection()
    client.on_message     = test.message()
    client.on_publish     = test.publisher()
    client.on_disconnect  = test.disconnection()

    # for lights
    client.on_connect     = light.connection()
    client.on_message     = light.message()
    client.on_publish     = light.publisher()
    client.on_disconnect  = light.disconnection()
    #for sensor
    client.on_connect     = occupancy_sensor.connection()
    client.on_message     = occupancy_sensor.message()
    client.on_disconnect  = occupancy_sensor.disconnection()

    def publishing():
        client.publish("testtopic/5", 1)
        while True:
            msg = occupancy_sensor.messages # calling for the variable "messages" to get PUBLISH messages
            topic = occupancy_sensor.topic
            if msg == "1" and topic == "testtopic/4":
                if is_circadian_Light("device2") == 1 :
                    client.publish("testtopic/Bedroom",tunable_light.circadianLight())
                    time.sleep(10)
            # The problem here is that if someone enters the kitchen I can't send messages to lights in the bedroom

            if msg == "1" and topic == "testtopic/5":
                if is_circadian_Light("device2") == 1 :
                    client.publish("testtopic/Kitchen",tunable_light.circadianLight())
                    time.sleep(10)

    pub = threading.Thread(target= publishing)
    pub.start()
    client.loop_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\nCtrl+C pressionado, encerrando aplicacao e saindo...")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Here is the `on_message` callback in the class Mqtt:

```
    def message(self):
        def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
            Message = str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
            self._messages = Message
            self._topic = msg.topic
            print("[Receiving msg] Topic:" +msg.topic+" / Message: "+Message)
        return on_message
```

I don't know if I need an object for every sensor so I can publish to multiple rooms at the same time, but if there are other solutions it will be better

Comment: I just want to mention also that I tried to create two objects for each sensor from the class Mqtt and it also didn't work, it's only publishing to the kitchen!

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the callback functions once for a single client.

You have set them all 3 times, only the last set will be used.

```
client.on_connect     = occupancy_sensor.connection()
client.on_message     = occupancy_sensor.message()
client.on_disconnect  = occupancy_sensor.disconnection()
```

Comment: But I am able to send messages to the light having the second set of callbacks. How is that possible if it is not used?

Comment: Before trying to send to two different topics it was working well! I was able to receive a message from the sensor and then send back messages to the light using ```client.publish("testtopic/Bedroom",tunable_light.circadianLight())```, and using two sets of callbcks

Comment: You are right the problem is in receiving messages, it only gets messages from the last set of callbacks. But what can I do, having a class Mqtt, to call the functions that returns the callbacks for each device, only in a single set?